# how can i execute a php file with win7-chrome-xampp?

Tags: php, google-chrome, windows-7, xampp, localhost

i have the xampp application (version 1.7.4) installed on win7 and my browser is google chrome. i've been testing a web site on my local server before uploading it on the web. it doesn't seem to find the local host so it's not working.

it used to work fine with winxp-firefox. any ideas?
thanks

Comment: are you trying to access via 127.0.0.1 or localhost?

Comment: have you tried via 127.0.0.1? I had the same problem on wampp and accessing the localhost ip worked fine

Comment: I'll post it as an answer for the rep :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of accessing via `localhost`, access via `127.0.0.1`